# StreamReader ReadLine returns null when not EOF

Tags: c#, streamreader, readline, eof

Having a strange problem that I've never encountered nor heard of happening.  It seems that occasionally, the ReadLine() function of the StreamReader class will return NULL, as if it's at the end of the file, BUT it's not.

My log file indicates that everything is happening just as if it had actually reached the end of the file, but yet it's only processing part of it.  There doesn't appear to be any consistency, because if I restart the process from scratch, the whole file is processed without incident.

Clearly, there is nothing funky in the file itself, or it would do this on the same line each time, plus it has happened with a few different files, and each time they are re-run, it works fine.

Anyone run across anything similar, or have any suggestions on what might be causing such a thing?

Thanks,

Andrew

Sample:

```
line = _readerStream.ReadLine();

if (null != line)
{
    eventRetVal = loadFileLineEvent(line);
}
else
{
    // do some housecleaning and log file completed
}
```

_readerStream is the stream which has been opened elsewhere.

loadFileLineEvent is a delegate that gets passed in which processes the line.  This has its own error handling (with logging), so there's no issue in there.

The routine above (not shown in its entirety) has error handling around it also (with logging), which is not being triggered either.

It's getting to the "else" and logging that it reached the end of the file, but it's obvious from the number of records I got that it didn't.

Comment: It might help if you post the code where you are doing the reading.  It may be due to how you are using the `StreamReader`.

Comment: Post a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: Sorry, but I can't post the code because it's work-related and not my personal stuff.  There's really nothing much going on besides the ReadLine() statement being assigned to a variable and then that variable being checked for a NULL value.  I was just hoping someone might have run across a similar situation, wasn't expecting anyone to try to fix my actual code.

Comment: @StarfleetSecurity i am not asking your *real (and possibly big) code*, post a minimal sample code that shows your case..

Comment: Are you reading binary data that may contain a NULL within the file itself?

Comment: Added basic sample to original post.

It's a standard text file, which I've checked thoroughly for anything that might be causing the issue.  Plus, on a second run, it works fine.

Comment: Is the file being read over a network share where you may periodically have a hiccup in the connection?

Comment: Most likely, someone is still writing to the file. Since `StreamReader` reads in batches, it might have already gotten to the end of a file even before you call the "last" `ReadLine`, and then it just quits. The point is, don't start reading the file until it's completely written and closed.

Comment: PSTRJDS -- I had considered something like that, but no, it's on the local machine.  LUAAN -- No, this is a static file that is strictly being read from, no writing occurs.

Comment: I have the same issue with a CODA file, in my case a subfunction also reads lines :-)

Comment: same problem ...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a more traditional approach to reading the stream? This way your checking for the end of the stream before reading the next potentially empty/null line. Seems like your code should work, but with a possible null exception thrown for trying to read a line that doesn't exists(not sure if SR throws for that though).

```
 using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(OFD.FileName))
 {
     while (!SR.EndOfStream)
     {
         string CurrentLine = SR.ReadLine();
         var eventRetVal = loadFileLineEvent(CurrentLine);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Seems like this would be an answer to the opposite problem from what I'm seeing.  The issue is that it thinks it's gotten to the end of the file, but it hasn't.  In your example, even if EndOfStream was still false (which it should be), the ReadLine() would still be returning NULL for me when this happens.  Which of course is the whole problem, that it's returning NULL but it's NOT at the end of the file.

Comment: my problem has been solved by using the code snippet from this solution