# streamreader readline returns nothing when not eof

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, text-files

I have a similar issue as [StreamReader ReadLine returns null when not EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314889/streamreader-readline-returns-null-when-not-eof) which I cannot figure out. The code is not complicated so I guess if it is really necessary:

```
Dim myFile As StreamReader

If Not myFile.EndOfStream Then
    'Ignore header
    myFile.ReadLine()       
    Dim line As Integer = 0
    Do Until myFile.EndOfStream
        line += 1
        Dim currentLine = myFile.ReadLine()
        'At the point line = 4 currentLine is Nothing - why??
        processLine(currentLine)
    Loop
End If
```

I can guarantee you that the file contains many more lines that 4 and no line is empty. The file is a bar ('|') delimited text file (*.txt) with 250 columns in it and how the file is created don't ask me that question. All I can say I have never had a problem up until recently with this one troublesome file, so how do I determine what the issue is. I have opened the file in NotePad++ and all seems ok. The consequence of file being corrupt if I stand correct is the program throws an exception as the process functions assumes it is not blank or if I choose to ignore blank line then it makes my code go into an infinite loop.

Furthermore please note I am actually trying to edit legacy code (classic asp) so I need to translate it back to vbscript when I am done which uses a TextStream object which is similar to the code I have so I do not want to make it to complicated, i.e. no fancy .NET framework calls. I was using .NET to debug it.

Comment: The code you have and the problem you have got nothing to do with classic ASP, period. If you'll want to convert it to classic ASP in the future, post a new question. The tag here is **invalid**. /cc @Lankymart

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader.Peek` returns `-1` on EOF, not `0`, so it’s reasonable for you to be getting `Nothing` rather than exiting the loop when EOF is reached.

If you have a file name, it’s probably easier to do this with [`System.IO.File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), and that will also solve the `Peek` problem:

```
For Each line In File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(1)
    processLine(line)
Next
```

Comment: What version of .NET as I am using 4.5 I don't see that method

Comment: @Glen: I forgot the `File` bit, sorry.

Comment: @Glen: VBScript is so completely different from VB.NET that it's probably not worth asking any questions about the former using examples with the latter. So how about ignoring that part and checking whether this works to see whether what you expect the file to contain and what it actually contains match?

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried your method with the ReadLines and the code exits the for loop which is great however it still only read three lines so the file must be corrupt. Is there anyway on this site to attach my file? Perhaps you can look at it

Comment: @Glen no way to attach files here, but there are many free temporary file hosting services, where you can upload a file and get a unique link for it, valid for short period of time. You can upload it to one of those, then share the link in a comment.